# Using htaccess to remove subfolder from URL of wordpress folder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've tried several of the answers listed on the site however have not found a solution that works (although the scenario is pretty straightforward). I have the following setup:

public directory (Zend Framework)

-> wordpress directory

-> css

-> img

-> etc.

The .htaccess in the public directory is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The .htaccess in the wordpress directory is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

All I want to do is remove 'wordpress' from the URL so that instead of 'www.mysite.com/wordpress/about' the user will see 'www.mysite.com/about'. I would like to do this only with htaccess, without changing wordpress files since there are more rules to be added later on.